# How does Berkeley's idealism differ from others that might be called idealist

Tags: phenomenology, idealism, berkeley

Having read Berkeley's work, I am aware of his theory, and definitely disagree with large parts of it - I would like to know how his idealism compares with that of other philosophers, particularly those of the early modern period though information about early idealist views would also be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. For some comparison with Kant and Schopenhauer, see http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/34167/10699