Does postmodern philosophy abandon the pursuit of “ultimate questions"? If so, how do people develop values without it?
Philosophers from Descartes to Kant have engaged deeply with “ultimate questions”—metaphysical issues about the nature of reality, certainty, and universal truths. However, postmodern philosophy appears to have shifted away from these pursuits, critiquing the very idea of universal answers and certainty.

Is it true that people basically gave up hope on definite answers to those ultimate questions?

If postmodernism denies the possibility of certainty or universal truths, how do people develop coherent values, worldviews, or ethical frameworks within this paradigm?


I’m interested in understanding both the philosophical rationale behind this shift and its practical implications for individuals.

See Critique to Postmodernism.

I apologize, but Habermas' critique to Postmodernism from Mauro's link is completely incomprehensible for me. Can someone translate?

You don’t have to view this way, instead you can view postmodern philosophy as less ambitious attempts to deconstruct the same problem in a more clearly defined and much more granular perspective and fashion…

@MauroALLEGRANZA Don't you think that's a bit unfair? That is like recommending Christopher Hitchens to help understand Christianity. ;)

@JoWehler I'm not the white knigt that you are looking for :-) :-( but it may be useful to note the comment "That postmodernists openly respond to Habermas is due to the fact that he takes postmodernism seriously and does not, like other critics, reject it as mere nonsense." || A beginner's (mine) intepreptation may be: 1. They use tools that" ...  commit a performative contradiction in their critiques of modernism by employing concepts and methods that only modern reason can provide." 2.  Hesees their ideas to be largely "self referential" and their defences of this claim to be inadequate....

eg "“Whoever transposes the radical critique of reason into the domain of rhetoric in order to blunt the paradox of self-referentiality, also dulls the sword of the critique of reason itself” "

@JoWehler This may help. Ot=r mot :-) :-(. But it my be useful either way. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34057/how-does-schopenhauer-maintain-idealism-without-god?rq=1

A psych prof in college said that your values are shown by how you spend your time, and how you spend your money. Look at those and work backwards to what caused those choices in you. You can explore territory you have no knowledge of, a map is not a prerequisite.

I think this question carries a fundamental misunderstanding of modern (post-Hegelian) philosophy in general and (noting that I dislike this term) postmodernist philosophy in particular. So it's worth looking at the historical trend.
Somewhere around the mid-19th century philosophers started coming to the conclusion that 'grand philosophy' — the pursuit of “ultimate questions”, as you put it — was increasingly academic and divorced from the actual human world. This isn't to say that philosophers thought such pursuits were intrinsically bad or wrong, but that they were at best idle attempts at establishing some imagined ideal state of humanity, and at worst counterproductive attempts (to use on overly evocative phrase) to polish a turd. Thinkers of that age could see wars becoming more brutal and destructive; they could see industry destroying land and communities; they could see Colonialism's intrinsic racism and dehumanization; they could see the coarse hypocrisies and dysfunctions of religion and ideology. What use were grand theories of philosophy when such were not applied, used, or even considered anywhere except scholarly works?
This led to the first wave of philosophical rebellion: Nietzsche-ism, existentialism, phenomenology, absurdism, and more obliquely Marxism and Freudianism. All of these in their way reconstituted the philosophical project, setting aside grand universal truth in favor of human truths: seeking out what it is to be human, looking for ways that people can escape and transcend the stultifying and corrupt rules and values transmitted and imposed by society. The general idea (across the board) was that if people could escape from societal constructs they could find a better and more authentic morality within and through themselves.
Then around the mid-20th century, a new generation of thinkers started coming to the conclusion that these new philosophical trends — while not nearly as detached from human life — weren't having the intended effect. Phenomenalism and existentialism were still largely academic pursuits; Marxism had collapsed into the same oppressive nonsense it was ostensibly trying to erase; Freudianism had peaked and faded as a human project, mainly replaced by clinical psychotherapy with its more limited goals… The effort to help individuals transcend social constructs didn't seem to be going anywhere, and so philosophers started digging into the nature of these social constructs.
in other words, philosophers started looking at how things like culture, social systems, group psychology, political organization, even language itself constrain, control, organize, and even constitute individuals. If people aren't able to break free of social constructs, then maybe the trick is to break down social constructs and rebuild them, reorienting individuals as a consequence. This is how we end up with with schools like post-structuralism, critical theory, feminism and cultural-awareness programmes, and all the approaches that try to deconstruct language or social elements to expose (and hopefully redress) structural biases and oppressions.
In sum, philosophy shifted from:

a (Classical Liberal) conception of humans as empowered individuals
bolstered by society, to…
a more problematic view of individuals as burdened by corrupt and
anachronistic social constraints that must be overcome, to…
a somewhat dire view of individuals as intractably enmeshed in
sociolinguistic webs that dictate both identity and social role

'Grand Theory' of the type posited only fits with the first conception, because it demands empowered individuals who can and will enact it. In the latter conceptions, the only type of 'Grand Theory' that's meaningful is one that somehow unlocks the cage that society and language place us in; we won't get back to the first type until until we can step into true humanness.

Interesting: whatever people try the cannot fill their "hole inside", i.e. find a reason or purpose, not even using philosophy.

@returntrue I don't find that mysterious at all. Why should there be one except for the obvious one (procreate)?

Why should procreation be an obvious purpose? I don't find that obvious at all.

Why should people strive for a purpose if there was none? If there is one, it makes perfect sense that people are empty until they have found it.

@returntrue: That sort of misses the point. A lot of people have purposes they dedicate their life to, but not all those purposes are cut from the same cloth.  Artists, firefighters, doctors, family people, industrial barons, career criminals, serial rapists, mass murderers, genocidal dictators: All of these people find 'reasons' and 'purposes'. As we go down the list, though, those 'reasons' and 'purposes' become progressively more outre.  Philosophy isn't meant to dictate reasons and purposes to people as much as straighten out and detoxify the reasons and purposes they already have.

@AnoE: Some people find meaning in procreation (whether by building a family or just by having a lot of sex). Others want to pass more down to history than their genes. Procreation isn't the be-all-and-end-all in human existence. Procreation is the default mode of the human animal; the thing almost everybody can do even if they can't do anything else.

I'm not saying that there is no other purpose than procreation. I am saying that procreation is the one obvious purpose of our physical bodies as gene carriers, like for every other animal and plant (and in fact any living thing, down to the lowliest bacterium). Any other purpose is optional (for some people) or non-obvious (for some people). I am not saying that there can not be any other, nor am I saying that everybody without fail must subscribe to procreation as prime motivator. @returntrue

Nonduality lets people out of the hall of mirrors, but they don't seem very interested in that. Maybe humans just aren't smart enough to solve humanity's problems?

@ScottRowe: It isn't a matter of intelligence. It's self-delusion. It's hard to find your way out of a box when you can't see the box you're in.

But, wouldn't people suspect that they are in a box, eventually? I did. Like at the beginning of The Matrix, where he thought something wasn't right and tried to find out more. Self-delusion is basically the first thing I started to consider, as a young teenager. The Who kind of blasted that message on the tannoy, so to speak. What are people listening to now? Lullabies? The one thing ancient Greek Philosophy produced that I think is worthwhile is the strong skeptic positions. Everyone should start their education there.

@ScottRowe: Most people do sense they're in a box, here and then. But part of the delusion is that most people think that idea is crazy and reject it. The mind is a subtle, subtle trap.

Philosophy as a science has nothing to do with utility. The atom bomb was devastating, but nevertheless knowledge in physics inevitably led to it. It is no different in philosophy. You examine things as things in themselves, what is time, what is space, etc. If you don't do that, it is not scientific philosophy as it has existed since Kant. It is more like sociology or psychology or "philosophy of life".

@tenebrisinkux: Science is a philosophy, not the other way around. Physical sciences inevitably made the atom bomb a possibility, but nothing in science said we had to make one, much less use it. Choosing whether to make such things is inevitably an act of philosophy that has no scientific basis.

@Ted Unfortunately, you don't know what science is. Science describes changes that are caused on immanent ground and the conditions that necessarily induce them (empirical science), or it is based on pure reasoning (under an axiom; mathematics or logic) or on justified principles (philosophy). Of course, science does not say that we should build an atomic bomb, but it was politically foreseeable that it would happen. But one cannot say that physics should not lead to it just because the atomic bomb is bad.

@tenebrisinkux: Insults won't serve you well here. I know what science is, and I know what it isn't. And since you've just admitted my point, you also know that I know. No one suggests that knowing how to build the atom bomb is bad. But the question of whether we should actually build one is an intrinsically moral/philosophical question that has nothing at all to do with science. This is not a point you can evade, and trying to ignore it will reflect badly on your reasoning style.

No, science and philosophy are two different things.
Philosophy
Logic, mathematics
Empirical science
Philosophy is a science that only deals with pure reason itself, all other sciences are not philosophy. The difference is very important because philosophy has very strict limits. Philosophy is a humanities science. It is not about whether something is good or bad. The will is either free or unfree. It does not become free just because an unfree will is bad, if philosophy is understood as a science. In the philosophy of life, things are of course different.

I would like to quote Kant on this, but I have to look for an English version if you don't speak German.

@tenebrisinkux: No, that's wrong.  Enough said…

If you simply don't want to admit to making a mistake, then i don't need to quote. It's not a problem to make mistakes, it can happen to anyone, but you can't say things that are wrong. Reminds me of postmodern philosophy, the main thing is to postulate things dogmatically and never admit mistakes.

From your answer, it seems that philosophers indeed shifted focus from those classic metaphysical questions, right? Why did you say my question carries misunderstanding of postmodern philosophy?

@DanielMendoza: First, because 'postmodern' is an umbrella term, not a philosophy: it covers maybe a half-dozen different theoretical positions whose only commonalities are that they (1) investigate the impact of language, and (2) came to prominence after WWII. Second, because philosophy didn't abandon the search for 'ultimate answers' (to the extent that it could ever be characterized that way), it merely started wondering whether we were asking the right questions. Thinking that we're looking in the wrong place doesn't mean one is giving up the search.


Does postmodern philosophy abandon the pursuit of “ultimate questions"? If so, how do people develop values without it?

Absolutely. In radical forms, "ultimate questions" make no sense because of radical skepticism, relativism, and radical visions of ambiguity and value. Questions about reality, causality, and God dominate the postmodern Western canon, but introducing ideas like radical interpretation, relativism, deconstruction and critical theory make it hard for the average Joe to know if there's meaning at all, when it seems both technically impossible and conspiratorial.
And yet you correctly note that hope springs eternal, and people persist in public meaning, and personal meaning, and grand sweeping metaphysical frameworks in the face of the naysayers. Psychologically speaking, humans seem to be universally predisposed towards cultivating coherent worldviews. The short of it is that human beings are the product of evolution, and the development of the worldview, and philosophical systems, and even the selection of truths seems to be driven ultimately by biological impulses and biases. Kierkegaard, for instance, acknowledged the importance of embracing emotions, and talked about love and anxiety. "Ultimately questions" are intimately tied to such emotions.
Another view on why people seem to pursue "ultimate questions" in light of the abyss of post-modernist thinking that reduces people to unimportant or trivial facts is narrative identity theory. From WP:

The theory of narrative identity postulates that individuals form an identity by integrating their life experiences into an internalized, evolving story of the self that provides the individual with a sense of unity and purpose in life.1 This life narrative integrates one's reconstructed past, perceived present, and imagined future. Furthermore, this narrative is a story – it has characters, episodes, imagery, a setting, plots, and themes and often follows the traditional model of a story, having a beginning (initiating event), middle (an attempt and a consequence), and an end (denouement). Narrative identity is the focus of interdisciplinary research, with deep roots in psychology.

Thus, if you subscribe to a naturalized epistemology, the answer to your question is a complicated one and lies withing both psychology and the philosophy of psychology. The suggestion, of course, lies in our evolutionary history. Our brains, no matter how persuasive complicated and abstract arguments are, drive us towards making sense of the world with worldviews, narratives, and personal meaning informed by "ultimate questions", Derrida be damned.

That we want to make sense and meaning of this life could be explained by evolutionary factors, or simply by the fact that there is said sense and meaning.

@returntrue I would say with the exception of the position of radical nihilism, no one questions sense and meaning; as an absurdist, however, I would simply reply that scrutinizing sense and meaning can lead to truths and facts that reject the idea that personal narratives are adequate representations of physical reality. That is, we chose our narratives, and when doing so, always are seeking an emotional payoff. This is why the variety of sense and meaning is diverse as the people who pursue it.

Okay, so what is your take on sense and meaning then?

@returntrue That's an interesting ask. In a nutshell, sense and meaning are largely byproducts of natural language, and we adopt natural language because it fosters communication and makes our representation far more sophisticated. Sense and meaning are the cognitive processes that allows us to extend our intelligence and exist in a society.

@returntrue I'm trying to characterize a position somewhere softer than Rorty's neopragmatism but somewhat firmer than a blind obedience to scientific realism. Truth and fact are psychological products.

David Loy wrote a helpful book called "The World is Made of Stories"

You have to understand that postmodern philosophy is not philosophy. It is an ideological concept that pursues political ideologies. Postmodern philosophy wants to implement its ideological standpoints in society, and like any other ideology, it postulates certain assumptions dogmatically. It is strange that this ideology has spread so widely. It is probably due to the phenomenon that Nietzsche already mentioned. People who are decadent want to change the world, and of course the world must be changeable, which is incompatible with objective reality. On the other hand, some errors in thinking have entered philosophy via Foucault, which can be traced back to Nietzsche. Some of Nietzsche's statements here were wrong, but they should not have led to the kind of ideology that has now happened. Here Nietzsche was anti-dogmatic (see his contributions to intellectual conscience). Postmodern philosophy should be considered a religion or ideology, so the term is misleading. Kant and other philosophers practiced real philosophy, one has nothing to do with the other. Every real philosopher wants real proofs, just like every mathematician.

IMO Heidegger followed-through on Kant and took the transcendental unity of apperception and its grounding (the "unconditioned necessity") on to indeterminate Being, which cannot even be defined. Then Derrida (postmodernist) grouped the words connected to presence as 'transcendental signifiers', which means they're such complicated historical words that they simply mean different things to different people.
If Kant and Heidegger do their best to set a direct course in the classical philosophy (Newtonian, as it were), then deconstruction and postmodernism is the quantum theory that complicates the classical.  But the classical course can still be seen. (Actually, Kant's motive for existentialism was not simply for the 'classic' understanding of existence but to found the basis for his system of morality.)
In the case of Being, postmodernism may make what was already indeterminate maybe less 100% indeterminate, or maybe 200% indeterminate, lol.  In this theme is a lot of preoccupation with the understanding and elucidation of existence; it's relevant all round (but not the only topic in philosophy).  But on this topic a postmodern dimension does not "deny the possibility" of navigating the question of existence.

You can trace a path through Heidegger, that's true, but it's only one path. There are several paths to what we call postmodern philosophy today. Another path is through Foucault. Or through Hegel and Marx to the Frankfurt School. There are different paths, but none of them are serious philosophical ones. You build something out of the mistakes of the thinkers that you want. Like a construction kit.
